# How to get internet access from MinGW64?

Tags: mingw, ping, mingw-w64

After installing MinGW64 on Windows 7, I try:

```
$ ping www.example.com
```

I get the error:

> > Ping request could not find host www.example.com. Please check the name and try again.

The internet connection from Windows is fine.

Is there anything else I have to do to connect MinGW64 to the internet?

Answer (score 1):

The firewall is blocking WiFi access from the MinGW64 console.

From a USB WiFi key using an external internet provider, everything is fine.